# Trying to create a simple QML program where a user can select a video file and it starts playing it

Tags: qt, qml

The program runs but when i select the video file it shows the error "Cannot assign [undefined] to QUrl" on the File Dialog onAccepted function. It seems like fileDialog.fileUrl is of type QUrl but mediaPlayer.source is an undefined type.

This is my code

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Dialogs
import QtMultimedia

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: "Video Player"

    MediaPlayer {
        id: mediaPlayer
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: videoOutput
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        title: "Select Video File"
        nameFilters: ["Video Files (*.avi *.mp4 *.mkv)"]

        onAccepted: {
            mediaPlayer.source = fileDialog.fileUrl
            console.log(fileDialog.fileUrl)
            mediaPlayer.play()
        }
    }

    Button {
        text: "Select Video File"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onClicked: fileDialog.open()
    }

    Button {
        text: mediaPlayer.source
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no property `fileUrl` in `FileDialog`. You should use [selectedFile](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html#selectedFile-prop).

Comment: Also you need to assign the `VideoOutput` to the [videoOutput](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html#videoOutput-prop) property of the `MediaPlayer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no property `fileUrl` in `FileDialog`. You should use [selectedFile](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html#selectedFile-prop). Also you need to assign the `VideoOutput` to the [videoOutput](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html#videoOutput-prop) property of the `MediaPlayer`.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Dialogs
import QtMultimedia

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Video Player")

    MediaPlayer {
        id: mediaPlayer
        videoOutput: videoOutput
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: videoOutput
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        title: qsTr("Select Video File")
        nameFilters: ["Video Files (*.avi *.mp4 *.mkv)"]

        onAccepted: {
            mediaPlayer.source = fileDialog.selectedFile
            mediaPlayer.play()
        }
    }

    Button {
        text: qsTr("Select Video File")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onClicked: fileDialog.open()
    }
}
```